# How to only check true/false value for boolean or undefined union type in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, union-types

I have two boolean | undefined variables

```
const condition1: boolean | undefined = xxx; // xxx is a return value from another method
const condition2: boolean | undefined = xxx;
```

I want to get the result of `condition1 && condition2`, but `undefined` should be excluded (meaning only the `true/false` matters, `undefined` is invalid and should not be compared)

so it should be

```
if(condition1 !== undefined && condition2 !== undefined) {
    return condition1 && condition2;
}
if(condition1 !== undefined && condition2 === undefined) {
    return condition1;
}
if(condition1 === undefined && condition2 !== undefined) {
    return condition2;
}
if(condition1 === undefined && condition2 === undefined) {
    return true;
}
```

how can I simplify the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put them into an array, filter out `undefined`s and then check that `.every` is true:

```
return [condition1, condition2]
  .filter(cond => cond !== undefined)
  .every(Boolean);
```

Answer (score 0):

[?? operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) should be recommended.

```js
return ((condition1 ?? condition2) && (condition2 ?? condition1)) ?? true
```